# Suma de varios dropdownlist en Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, dropdownlist

Amigos, Tengo 2 `dropdownlist`. Ambos los puedo sumar, tengo ya el código `Jquery` pero mi problema es que los tengo que seleccionar en orden para que se sumen, es decir primero el `select` de "tamaño" y después el de "Masa" y a la hora de seleccionar una opción no me suma si la cambio a otra, espero poder explicarme bien. Y bueno lo que necesito es que se sume independientemente del orden de los `dropdown` y que pueda cambiar la opción a otra y sumarse igual.

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tamano").change(function(event){
    valor = this.value;
    precioTamano = $('option:selected', this).data('precio');
  });

  $("#masa").change(function(event){
    valor = this.value;
    precioMasa = $('option:selected', this).data('precio');
    cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();

    var sum = precioTamano + precioMasa;

    $("#total").val(sum);
  });

});
```

HTML

```
      <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tamano" id="tamano">
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        @foreach ($tamanos as $tamano)
          <option value="{{ $tamano->id }}" data-precio="{{$tamano->precio}}">{{ $tamano->nombre }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>


      <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tipoPan" id="masa">
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        @foreach ($tipoPan as $masa)
          <option value="{{ $masa->id }}" data-precio="{{ $masa->precio }}">{{ $masa->nombre }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero lo siguiente:

```js
function calcularSuma(){
 
  tamano = $("#tamano option:selected").data('precio');
  if(tamano == '' || tamano == null){
   alert('Seleccione el Tamaño.');
    return false;
  }
 
  masa = $("#masa option:selected").data('precio');
  if(masa == '' || masa == null){
   alert('Seleccione la Masa.');
    return false;
  }
  
  total = tamano + masa;
  $("#total").val(total);
}//end function calcularSuma
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Tamaño:  <br>
<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tamano" id="tamano" onchange="calcularSuma();">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1" data-precio="10">10</option>
  <option value="2" data-precio="20">20</option>
  <option value="3" data-precio="30">30</option>
</select><br>
Masa:  <br>
<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tipoPan" id="masa" onchange="calcularSuma();">
  <option value=""  selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
  <option value="4" data-precio="40">40</option>
  <option value="5" data-precio="50">50</option>
  <option value="6" data-precio="60">60</option>
</select><br>
Total: <br>
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Total">
```

Lo primero que realizo es agregar el evento **onchange** en tus select ó dropdown en este evento invoco a una función **calcularSuma**.

dentro de esta función obtengo los valores respectivos de cada uno, ademas realizo una validación previa antes de sumar dichos valores mediante un if:

```
 if(tamano == '' || tamano == null){
    alert('Seleccione el Tamaño.');
    return false;
  }
```

y así con cada uno de los **select** para verificar que existan valores y posterior suma el resto seria sumar y agregar el valor total al **input** deseado.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Me sirvió perfecto. gracias amigo

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional con `jQuery`. En el bloque de código encuentras la explicación comentada. Este código lo puedes adaptar al tuyo.

```js
//Cuando se detecte algún cambio en el DOM
$(document).change(function(event){
  //Capturo el valor de precioTamano y precioMasa
  precioTamano = $('#tamano').val();
  precioMasa = $('#masa').val();
  //Compruebo si alguno de los dos está vacío
  if(precioTamano == "" || precioMasa == ""){
    //A la variable sum le asigno el valor 0
    var sum = 0;
  }else{
    //Si los dos ya tienen valor, hago la suma de los dos valores
    var sum = parseInt(precioTamano) + parseInt(precioMasa);
  }
  //Muestro la suma
  $('#total').val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tamano" id="tamano">
  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1" data-precio="1">tamaño1</option>
  <option value="2" data-precio="2">tamaño2</option>
</select>

<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tipoPan" id="masa">
  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="15" data-precio="15">masa 15</option>
  <option value="23" data-precio="23">masa 23</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para tu caso, lo que hice fue crear una función con la operacion q buscas. Esa función se llama por cada select que cambie, pero solo se ejecuta si estan los 2 valores seteados.

En tu código, solo se ejecutaba cuando cambiaba el segundo valor.

```js
var precioMasa;
var precioTamano;
var valor;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tamano").change(function(event){
    valor = this.value;
    precioTamano = $('option:selected', this).data('precio');
    sumar();
  });

  $("#masa").change(function(event){
    valor = this.value;
    precioMasa = $('option:selected', this).data('precio');
    cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
    sumar();
  });

  function sumar(){
    if (precioTamano != null && precioMasa != null) {
      var sum = precioTamano + precioMasa;
      $("#total").val(sum);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tamano" id="tamano">
  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="7" data-precio="7">Tamaño</option>
</select>


<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tipoPan" id="masa">
  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="12" data-precio="12">Valor Masa</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Que pasaría en el caso que quisieras agregar un `select` más? Por ejemplo si además de la **masa** y el **tamaño** necesitas saber el **grosor**?

Me incline más por crear una función genérica que te serviría en ese caso

```js
var total = 0;

function calculo (id) {  
  let input = $(`#${id} option:selected`).data('precio');
  total += input;
  $("#total").val(total);
}
```

```html
<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tamano" id="tamano" onchange="calculo('tamano');">
  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="7" data-precio="7">Tamaño</option>
</select>

<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tipoPan" id="masa" onchange="calculo('masa');">
  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="12" data-precio="12">Valor Masa</option>
</select>

<!--<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tipoPan" id="grosor" onchange="calculo('grosor');">
  <option value="">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="20" data-precio="20">Valor Grosor</option>
</select>-->

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Cree una función que recibe un `id` que corresponde a tu `input select` y la suma se realiza de forma automática, sin esperar que se llenen los demás campos.

Espero que te sea de utilidad